# AJAX Dropdowns (HTML Select) in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have the following select option codes:

```
           <select name="startTime" id = "startTime" onchange = "javascript:timeChange();">

                    <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${param.cid != null}">
                                    <option value="<c:out value="${timevalue}"/>" selected><c:out value="${time}" /></option>
                                    <option value="<c:out value="-"/>"><c:out value="Choose time"/></option>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                    <option value="<c:out value="-"/>" selected><c:out value="Choose time" /></option>
                            </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    <option value="10:00:00" >10:00</option>
                    <option value="11:00:00" >11:00</option>
                    <option value="12:00:00" >12:00</option>
                    <option value="13:00:00" >13:00</option>
                    <option value="14:00:00" >14:00</option>
                    <option value="15:00:00" >15:00</option>
                    <option value="16:00:00" >16:00</option>
                    <option value="17:00:00" >17:00</option>
                    <option value="18:00:00" >18:00</option>
                    <option value="19:00:00" >19:00</option>
                    <option value="20:00:00" >20:00</option>
                    <option value="21:00:00" >21:00</option>
               </select>
```

and also have the following ajax code:

```
            $.ajax({
            url: "temporary_checking.jsp",
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            async: true,
            timeout:6000,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                    data = data.trim();
                    var n = data.indexOf("ERROR",0);
                    if( n > -1 ){
                            if(data.indexOf("ERROR 2",0) >= 0 ){
                                    alert("Error to allocate time slot");
                                    return true;
                            }
                    }else{
                            window.location.reload(false);
                            if(getCookie('Times') != null || getCookie('Times') != undefined)
                            {
                                    deleteCookie('Times');
                            }
                            setCookie('reload',1,'');
                            setCookie('zerosecond',1,'');
                    }
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    document.getElementById('startTime').value = "-";
                    alert("Error to book time slot : " + textStatus + '\n ' + errorThrown);
                    return false; 
            }
        });
```

So, the problem is whenever it selects an option e.g 17:00 then the value will be back to default which is "Choose time" option. It has no problem on FireFox, however. Any solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are call the function "window.location.reload(false);" the page will immediately reloaded, all JS states will be lost and the code lines after this statement will not be executed. So it's better to set the cookie before the reload:

```
...

} else {
    if (getCookie('Times') != null || getCookie('Times') != undefined) {
        deleteCookie('Times');
    }
    setCookie('reload',1,'');
    setCookie('zerosecond',1,'');
    window.location.reload();
}
...
```

The "false" parameter makes no sense for me, because it is the default value:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

Comment: thanks. But the problem is, the selected index/option is reset to default value i.e "Choose time". All i need is the selected index is changed.

Comment: I don't really understand the workflow of your code. Why do you need a reload? user input -> data validation -> show message ?

Comment: I know that with ajax it's not necessary to do reload. But somehow, i use it in order to get the result as needed. So, the workflow is: user input -> data validation -> show message is correct.