# selected index reload in chrome, safari, and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

This is actually the continuation of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847687/ajax-dropdowns-html-select-in-chrome). I traced and found that on browsers like chrome, safari, and IE, it didn't work because of reload. Therefore, is there any method instead of window.location.reload() that is compatible with chrome, safari, or IE? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope. Can't reproduce it except in IE7. You could simple try `location.reload` for browsers that don't support the `window` object.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy:it's still the same ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an alternate way to reload the page rather than `location.reload()`; you can also use:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

Another (but similar) way:

```
window.location = document.URL;
```

Yet other ways:

```
window.location.assign(document.URL);
// or
window.location.replace(location.href); // this will prevent the page to be saved in browser history (back button will not navigate to previous page);
// or
history.go(0); // (not recommended) history object is not public standard but all major browsers support it.
```

*Note that `location.reload()` takes a `boolean` parameter. It's default value is `false` which reloads the page from the **cache**. If you set it to `true` it will force the browser to get the page from the server.*

**After reading your other post** (I don't know if you've considered [Soc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14864720/112731) but); instead of setting cookies, I think you can also set/get the data from the query-string values in the new URL:

To pass some data to the redirected page:

```
// pass the selected index:
var selectedIndex = $('#select-box')[0].selectedIndex;
window.location.href = window.location.href + '?selIndex=' + selectedIndex;

// pass the selected value:
var selectedValue = encodeURIComponent($('#select-box').val());
window.location.href = window.location.href + '?selValue=' + selectedValue;
```

To get the data from the query-string:

```
function queryStringToObject(strQS)
{
    var qs = {};
    var pairs = strQS.split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++)
    {
        var key_val = pairs[i].split('=');
        if (key_val.length > 0)
            qs[key_val[0]] = key_val[1] && decodeURIComponent(key_val[1]);
    }
    return qs;
}

var strQS = 'field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3';
var qs = queryStringToObject(strQS);
console.log(qs);
```

This will output:

```
{ field1: "value1", field2: "value2", field3: "value3" }
```

You can use `window.location.search.substring(1)` to get the query-string from the current URL.

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is the selected index when it comes to reload, its value is reset into default value i.e "Choose time". Is there any way to execute ajax data and url without reload?

Comment: Do you want to set the previously selected index back when the page reloads? Or prevent the page from reloading when the user selects an item from the select box?? Why do you reload the page in your ajax's callback (with `window.location.reload(false);`)?

Comment: OK, it's my mistake. Actually, I want to prevent the page from reloading when the user selects an item for select box. I realize that using ajax, it is not necessary to do reload. But, somehow it didn't work without reload which made me added it to the code. Anyway, any advice for this?

Comment: What doesn't work without reload? You don't get the ajax response? See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/onury/TQmrE/ I use Google Chrome and this works as expected.

Comment: thanks. Btw, data is actually "var data = "startdatetime="+choosingDateTime;". Is it correct to put "html" as dataType? or should I use "script"? If so, how am i supposed to write the data? Is it still the same as "var data = "startdatetime="+choosingDateTime;"?